# Is there a name for a topological space $X$ in which every proper closed subset is compact?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, compactness

Is there a name for a topological space $X$ in which every proper closed subset is compact$^{(*)}$? [It is well known that](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Subspace_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact) in a compact topological space, every closed set is compact. Hence, the class of compact spaces is contained in the class of spaces with $(*)$ property.

Comment: The total space $X$ should be closed in any topology, so what you find is just a compact space.

Comment: Thx for this note, i fixed it.

Comment: Do you have an interesting example of such a space?

Comment: I believe it still has to be compact.  Otherwise you can find a proper  sequence in the space with no accumulation point.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317724/topological-spaces-in-which-every-proper-closed-subset-is-compact