# If all closed subsets of a set are compact, does it follow that this set is subset of a compact set?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

It is well known that closed subsets of compact sets are themselves compact. Now the reverse is not true: A set of which all closed subsets are compact needs not to be compact itself; for example, consider non-closed bounded sets in $\mathbb R^n$.

However those sets are themselves subsets of compact sets (as bounded sets, they are subsets of closed balls, which are compact). And it is obvious that the initially quoted theorem also holds for arbitrary subsets of compact sets, since the subset relation is transitive.

However I wonder: Can there exist a set in some topological space, no matter how weird, such that all closed subsets of that set are compact, but the set itself is not the subset of a compact set?

There was a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317724/topological-spaces-in-which-every-proper-closed-subset-is-compact) that asked about the case where all proper closed subsets of a topological space are compact, and the conclusion was that the space itself is compact. However if this helps with the subset case, then I don't see how.

**Clarification:** Since it seems to have caused a lot of confusion in the comments: In the context of my post, “closed” is to be understood in the topology of the full space, not in the subspace topology of the subset (those are *very* different notions of “closed”!)

Comment: A set is one of its closed subset. So…

Comment: @Bernard: I don't understand. An open ball certainly is not a closed subset of itself, is it?

Comment: Yes it is: $X$ is always closed in $X$.

Comment: Any space is contained in its one-point compactification.

Comment: $\varnothing`$ and $X$ are both open, hence closed, in $X$.

Comment: @Mindlack: But the set I'm considering is *not* the complete space, and the closedness I'm considering is the closedness related to the total space, which is *not* the same as closedness in the subspace topology. For example, in $\mathbb R$, the interval $(0,1)$ has the property that all its closed subsets are compact (because they are closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb R$). But when considering the subspace topology of $(0,1)$ that is *not* true (in particular, in the subspace topology, $(0,1)$ itself is closed, but certainly not compact).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: But the closed sets of the one-point compactification are not the same as the closed sets of the original space.

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: @bof: If you post your example as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @bof Thank you! Very cool.

Comment: @bof: Thank you. So in essence, you have to make quite strong assumptions to prevent such examples, but metric spaces are strong enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $X$ be the space of countable ordinals with the order topology (a locally compact Hausdorff space, completely normal, but not metrizable), and let $Y$ be the set of all isolated points of $X$.

Every subset of $Y$ which is closed in $X$ is finite, since every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point in $X$. (An infinite set of ordinals contains an increasing sequence; the limit of an increasing sequence of countable ordinals is a countable ordinal, i.e., an element of $X$.

$Y$ is not contained in any compact subset of $X$ because no uncountable subset of $X$ is compact or even Lindelöf.

**P.S.** Here is another example, a first countable, separable, locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ with a dense open subset $Y$ such that: $Y$ is countable and discrete; the only subsets of $Y$ which are closed in $X$ are the finite sets; and $Y$ is not contained in any countably compact subset of $X$.

Let $\mathcal A$ be an infinite maximal almost disjoint family of infinite subsets of $\omega$. $\mathcal A$ must be uncountable, as there is no maximal almost disjoint family of cardinality $\aleph_0$. Let $X$ be the corresponding $\Psi$-space, that is, $X=Y\cup\mathcal A$ where $Y=\omega$, and a set $U\subseteq X$ is *open* if $A\setminus U$ is finite for each $A\in U\cap\mathcal A$. All the properties claimed above are easily verified; the fact that every infinite subset of $Y=\omega$ has a limit point in $X\setminus Y=\mathcal A$ follows from the maximality of the almost disjoint family $\mathcal A$.

Unlike the previous example, this space $X$ is not normal; if $\mathcal A_0$ is a countably infinite subset of $\mathcal A$, then $\mathcal A_0$ and $\mathcal A\setminus\mathcal A_0$ are disjoint closed sets which can not be separated by open sets.

Comment: hmm, why does every infinite subset of $X$ contain a limit point in $X$?

Comment: Probably a good idea. And thanks again :) I'm trying to come up with a metric example/a proof it can't happen. I think that perhaps one can prove such a set $A$ is totally bounded and hence so is its closure, which means its closure is incomplete, which means one can find a Cauchy sequence in $A$ which is not convergent, so its set of points is closed in the whole space but not compact.

Comment: @Cronus: that’s pretty much it for your proof if $S$ is metric and $A$ is as required. Indeed, $\overline{A}$ can’t be compact, so there is a sequence $a_n \in \overline{A}$ without a limit point. Take $b_n \in A$ at distance $<1/n$ of $a_n$ and consider $B=\{b_n,\,n\}$. $B \subset A$ is closed in $S$ and is not compact.

Comment: @mindlack yes, I just wanted to work out the details. Perhaps I overcomplicated things a bit.

Comment: @bof Do you think it's possible to find a separable (Hausdorff) example, or even second countable?

Comment: @Cronus Good question. No idea.

Comment: @bof Here's a separable (Hausdorff) one: Take $\Bbb{R}^{\omega_1}$ (or even $\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}$) with the origin (i.e. the point all of whose coordinates are zero) removed. You can topologically embed $[0,\omega_1)$ in it by sending an ordinal $\alpha<\omega_1$ to the point all of whose coordinates up to and including $\alpha$ are zero. Then take (the image of) $Y$ from your answer; it's easy to see that it's not contained in any compact subset (since such a subset, when viewed as a subset of the whole product, must $\ni 0$), and every closed subset contained in it again must be finite.

Comment: Of course, $Y$ here is not separable (but $X=\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}\backslash \{0\}$ is). I am still curious if it's possible to find an example where it's separable too, or even where $X$ is second countable. Of course, such a space will necessarily not be normal (since otherwise it would be metrizable), so one has to look at rather weird spaces to find an example.

Comment: @bof Nice. This is a very cool example. Even locally compact! I'm still interested in a (Hasudorff) second countable example, but since it will not be locally compact or regular this is probably the "nicest" space one can find.

Comment: @bof By the way, I could be wrong (I'm definitely no expert in these matters), but I think you're using the axiom of choice in your first example too. It is consistent with ZF that a countable union of countable sets is uncountable. Perhaps one can work around that, though - I have really no idea how to deal with ordinals without choice.

Comment: @Cronus Good point, about AC. I guess "a countable union of countable sets is countable" requires a weaker form of choice than the existence of that maximal almost disjoint family. Anyway the second example seems somehow hazier to me. I think I'll just edit out all mention of the axiom.

Comment: @bof Yes, I bet it does require a weaker version. Still, probably a good idea not to mention it anyway. Here's an idea for an approach to a second countable example: Take a quotient of your second example where you identify collections of MAD families so that you'd remain with only countable many (e.g. take a co-countable subset and identify all of them to a point). I'm pretty sure this isn't compact (since you still have a closed, infinite, discrete subset) but I think it's no longer 1st-countable or even Hausdorff. Yet, I think something along these lines might work.

Comment: @Cronus It's too complicated for me. Do you think $X$ can be a paracompact Hausdorff space? A Lindelöf $T_3$ (regular Hausdorff) space?

Comment: @bof I would guess there is a paracompact Hausdorff example but not a Lindelöf $T_3$ example, but I have not proof or counterexample.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a proof this can't happen in a metric space. Suppose $X$ is a metric space and that $A\subseteq X$ is a subset such that every $B\subseteq A$ which is closed in $X$ is compact.

**Lemma**. $A$ is totally bounded.
*proof*. Assume it is not. Then there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that no finite collection of $\varepsilon$-balls cover $X$. Therefore we can define recursively a sequence of points $a_1,a_2,...$ each two of which are at distance at least $\varepsilon$ from one another. This is a subset of $A$ which is closed (if $x$ is in its closure then by taking an $\varepsilon/2$ neighbourhood of it we see we must have $x=a_n$ for some $n$) but clearly not compact (it's discrete and infinite).

**Corollary**. The closure of $A$ is totally bounded as well.

By assumption the closure of $A$ is not compact. Therefore, it's not complete, so it contains a Cauchy sequence which is not convergent. Therefore $A$ contains such a sequence as well. The set of points of this sequence is closed, but not compact. Contradiction.

Comment: Or, more directly, given a sequence in $\overline{A}$ with no convergent subsequence, you can pick a sequence in $A$ that approximates it in the limit and so has the same convergence subsequences.  So that sequence in $A$ forms a closed set which is not compact.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yeah, this was pointed out to me already. When I was trying to come up with a proof it just seemed to me like a good idea to first try to prove total boundedness (since I think this is essentially what's going on here), and then when I was done I didn't realise it wasn't really necessary.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet No, I just showed that the closure of $A$ contains such a sequence and then deduced $A$ itself does too.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind abandoning all separation axioms, then it's really easy to find an example, because you can easily make there be very few closed subsets of your set.  For instance, let $Y$ be any non-compact topological space, let $X=Y\times\{0,1\}$ where $\{0,1\}$ has the indiscrete topology, and let $A=Y\times\{0\}$.  Then *no* nonempty subset of $A$ is closed in $X$, but $A$ is not contained in any compact subset of $X$.